# Analog psp thumbstick not working with analog to digital converter on Pi model 2

Tags: driver, retropie, pi-2, joystick

I am working on a portable RPI 2 retropie (another version of Raspbian) powered game console.
I have bought an analog psp thumbstick, and an mcp3002 analog to digital converter, that I want to use for the project...
However, it seems like the mcp3002 ADC needs a driver for the Pi to register it...
So I've found a driver that should work on the old Pi, but I couldn't get it to work on the Pi 2, so I contacted the developer and found out that it would not work on the new RPI 2's CPU :(
So my question is if any of you have found a way, or know how to get the mcp3002 ADC to run on the Pi 2??

Any answers will be greatly appreciated! :)

Rasmus

Answer (score 0):

The MCP3002 is a SPI chip.

The Linux SPI driver works.

It may be helpful if you add details of what you are doing.

---

If SPI is properly enabled the following devices will be visible in /dev.

```
$ ls -l /dev/spi*
crw-rw---T 1 root spi 153, 0 Jan  1  1970 /dev/spidev0.0
crw-rw---T 1 root spi 153, 1 Jan  1  1970 /dev/spidev0.1
$
```

Comment: Hi Joan. Thanks for your quick reply! I have connected my analog joystick, the mcp3002 ADC and the RPI 2's GPIO via a bread board. Thanks for letting me know about the Linux SPI driver! I went and searched the web for it, and found a page on the official RPI Foundation website. I skimmed the page, and found out that the driver was already installed, but blacklisted. I cut this comment up in two parts because it was too long :)

Comment: -NEXT PART. I removed the Linux driver from the blacklist, just as it said. However it still doesn't work, but it's probably because I did something wrong, or missed something, though I don't know what. Can you tell me, or give me an a little bit more detailed guide?? I hope you will help a newbie like me out :)

Comment: What still doesn't work?  What does work?  You need to give details of what you are doing.  Preferably edit your original post to add the details.

Comment: Hi Joan. I have connected my analog joystick, the mcp3002 ADC and the RPI 2's GPIO via a bread board. I have unblacklisted the spi-mcp2708, by setting a # before it in the raspi-blacklist.conf. I have also downloaded, and installed the WiringPi, but i'm not sure if the Linux SPI driver works. How can I see if the Pi can read the mcp3002's input's? And how can I see exactly what they are?

Comment: @Rasmus see edited post.

Comment: Following your instructions, I see that there is no SPI* in  /DEV. So The SPI is not enabled, and I don't know how to enable it. Can you please help me out??

Comment: Almost certainly it's because of the move to device tree.  Add dtparam=spi=on to /boot/config.txt and then reboot.

Comment: Hi Joan. Now I can see: crw-rw---T 1 root spi 153, 0 Jan  1  1970 /dev/spidev0.0
crw-rw---T 1 root spi 153, 1 Jan  1  1970 /dev/spidev0.1 :) But how can I read values from the mcp3002, and see them??

Comment: Any old SPI software should work now.  You could use Python with the spidev module or C and talk direct to the driver.  spidev example at http://raspberry.io/projects/view/reading-from-a-mcp3002-analog-to-digital-converter/

Comment: Thank you so much :) I have another question, do you know how I can make the mcp3002 output control the cursor (So I use the analog thumbstick)?

Comment: Outside my field I'm afraid.  If you have any problems getting SPI to work and need to debug my [piscope](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html) will let you monitor the gpios.  You'd need to keep the SPI bit rate artificially low (100kbps say).

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I need :) I've run the installation script for both the Piscope and the pigpiod. But when I type sudo pigpiod it says: Can't lock /var/run/pigpio.pid pigpio initialisation failed. When I then try to run Piscope it gives an error message concerning retriving accessibility bus address, and informs me that the assertions DK_IS_WINDOW (window) and GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget) failed. It also says 'invalid unclassed pointed en cast to GtkWidget'. I hope you can help me out :)

Comment: You don't need pigpio to do SPI (though loading it won't do any harm).  If you're using python, try loading spidev as @joan said.  The gertboard uses an MCP3002 so you can use atod.py from http://raspi.tv/download/GB_Python.zip (though you'll have to figure out the wiring yourself with reference to theMCP3002 datasheet).